# JSP rendering too fast/slow in Chrome Browser

Tags: jsp, google-chrome

Am hitting a JSP page. In this JSP page, I have Jquery + Scriplets + some JSP tags (div, input, form etc) + Java Scripts.

This JSP page takes username as input from user. If user has not input his username but simply hits submit button the page will refresh and throw an error message. The page will refresh and hit the same URL (Error message is not shown in a new page)

In the process of user hitting Submit button and error message is thrown, Chrome Browser is also rendering other DIV elements in the JSP page for a flash of second and throwing the desired error message to user.

With Chrome browser rendering other elements (div, input etc) in the JSP when the same page is hit, it will give a picture of the other elements to users. This is not happening in IE and FF.

How to avoid this in Chrome?

**@Alfasin:** 
I have attached the JSP code below. Let me know if any other details are required.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="/static-files/css/jquery-ui-rev.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.Cookie"%>
<%
        String visitingCookie = "AUTHCookie";
        String urlCookie = "URLCookie";
    String movieCookieName="movieCookie";
        String displayOnlyPwd = "false";
        Cookie[] cookielist = request.getCookies();
        if(cookielist != null)
          {
              for(int i = 0; i<cookielist.length; i++)
               {
                  Cookie cookie = cookielist[i];
                  if(cookie.getName().contains(visitingCookie) && 
!cookie.getValue().equals(""))
                    {
                          displayOnlyPwd = "true";
                          request.setAttribute("AUTHCookie",cookie.getValue());
                          request.setAttribute("displayOnlyPwd",displayOnlyPwd);
                          break;
                   }
              }
        if(displayOnlyPwd.contains("false"))
        {
            request.setAttribute("displayOnlyPwd",displayOnlyPwd);
        }
       }
    else{
        displayOnlyPwd = "false";
        request.setAttribute("displayOnlyPwd",displayOnlyPwd);
    }
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#toopt a").tooltip({
    bodyHandler: function() {
        return $($(this).attr("href")).html();
    },
 });
   });

function delete_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
  var cookie_date = new Date ( );  
  cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
  document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
}

function checkpassword() 
{
var checkPassword=document.getElementById("password").value;
var counter=0;
var errMsg=" ";
var errMsg1=" ";

    if(checkPassword.length==0)
        {

         errMsg+="Please enter a valid Password.";
                     document.writeln("<form name=\"errForm\" method=\"POST\" action=\"http://myDomain/web/portal/home/-/portal/login?_58_redirect=%2Fweb%2Fportal%2Flogout\">");
         document.writeln("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"errMsg\" value=\"" + errMsg + "\">");
         document.writeln("</form>");
         document.errForm.submit(); 
         return false;
            }

}
function enableDisableForm(myVar)
{
if(myVar == "true")
{
$(document).ready(function()
            {
            $("#disableDivForm").dialog({
         autoOpen:true,
     position:'center',
        height:167,
        width: 472,
        modal: true

            });
            });



var div1 = document.getElementById("enableDivForm");
div1.style.display = "none";


}
else
{


var div2 = document.getElementById("disableDivForm");
div2.style.display = "none";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
```

I have pasted 50% of my code here. Another 50% to go. Do you require me to paste full code?

Regards,

Comment: Is my question clear? Any more information required on this?

Comment: without seeing your code it is (almost) impossible to help you.

Comment: @alfasin I have provided my code. Let me know if furthur details are required

Comment: if you don't want to post all the code - that's fine, but at least give us a link so we can see the described behavior. It's a very difficult guess work... ;)

Comment: @alfasin You can check the behaviour here http://122.248.244.96 I hope you are able to access this link. Click on Login without entering anything. In the process of user hitting Login and error message is thrown, Chrome Browser is also rendering other DIV elements in the JSP page for a flash of second and throwing the desired error message to user. Pls hit login link couple of times.

With Chrome browser rendering other elements (div, input etc) in the JSP when the same page is hit, it will give a picture of the other elements to users. This is not happening in IE.

Comment: It looks perfectly fine on my chrome 22.0

Comment: @alfasin Then it could be related to Network speed at my end. May be its bit slow than yours. This is the only possibility I can think of.

Comment: Could be. Anyways, a cool trick I learned is: upload the body with the attribute `"style= display: none;"` and only after you've done with uploading the page (as the last command in `ready` function if you're using jQuery) do: `$("#body).show();`

Comment: @alfasin Your cool trick works in my case. How can I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: I posted it as an answer - glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload the body with the attribute:
`"style= display: none;"`

and only after you've done with uploading the page (as the last command in ready function if you're using jQuery) do:

```
$("#body).show();
```